# How to get absolute difference between 2 cv::Mat object

Tags: ios, opencv

I need to find out difference between to matrices. I need to use it iOS, so I need the code in C++.

```
cv::Mat input1;
cv::Mat input2;

// input1 and input2 assigned with values.

dif = input1-input2

cv::Mat diff;
cv::absdiff(input1, input2, diff);

cv::MatExpr pct = 1 - (diff/(5*5));
```

I required to have `pct` as float or double and want to compare with another float value.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the OpenCV documentation that you can use the function [`absdiff`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6fef31bc8c4071cbc114a758a2b79c14):

```
cv::Mat absolute_difference;
cv::absdiff(input1, input2, absolute_difference);
```

Comment: Can we get difference in float or double?

Comment: Yes, but why don't you try yourself?

Comment: I tired for that but i'm getting it in cv::Mat only. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I can't unless you show some code. Please edit the question to add all required information